# How can i use mdi icons in angular 6

Tags: angular, icons, angular6

I am trying to configure [mdi](https://materialdesignicons.com/) icons with [@angular/material](https://material.angular.io/) in my mini-project. I have tried several tutorials but with no avail.

When registering the icon set following the tutorial (as shown below), I get some errors...

```js
constructor(matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { 
  matIconRegistry.addSvgIconSet(domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/mdi.svg'));
}
```

Here is my code...

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MatIconRegistry, MatToolbarModule, MatIconModule } from '@angular/material';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
  AppComponent
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**styles.scss**

```css
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Roboto);

$BasicColor: #76b3c8;
body {
  #basic {
    background-color: $BasicColor;
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PruebaAngular</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<mat-toolbar id="basic">
  <span>Home</span>
</mat-toolbar>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**angular.json**

```
...
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
      ...
      "assets": [
        "src/favicon.ico",
        "src/assets",
        { "glob": "**/*", "input": "./assets/", "output": "./assets/" },
        { "glob": "favicon.ico", "input": "./", "output": "./" },
        { "glob": "mdi.svg", "input": "../node_modules/@mdi/angular-material", "output": "./assets" }
      ],
    }
  },
}
...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-mdi

#### Install NPM package

Use the following command to install npm package for @mdi/angular-material

```
npm install @mdi/angular-material --save
```

#### Include `mdi.svg` to the list of compiled assets

Add `node_modules/@mdi/angular-material/mdi.svg` to the list of `assets` in your `angular.json` file using the `glob` syntax

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets",
  { "glob": "mdi.svg", "input": "node_modules/@mdi/angular-material/", "output": "./assets" }
],
```

**Validate that `mdi.svg` is correctly copied to `assets` folder**

To validate if `mdi.svg` file is correctly copied to the `assets` folder run `ng build` and look into the generated `dist/assets` folder to see if the `mdi.svg` is present. If not, you might have to adjust the `glob` input path as it is relative to the workspace root. See [project assets documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration) for details on how include assets via `angular.json` file.

#### Register SVG icon set to @angular/material icon registry

Register the svg icon set with `matIconRegistry` in the constructor of your `AppModule`

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatIconRegistry, MatIconModule } from '@angular/material';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatIconModule, // you have to import MatIconModule into your app
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, domSanitizer: DomSanitizer){
    matIconRegistry.addSvgIconSet(domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/mdi.svg'));
  }
}
```

#### Usage

You will be able to use `mat-icon` component specifying the desired icon with `svgIcon` property

```html
<!-- Icon by itself -->
<mat-icon svgIcon="android"></mat-icon>

<!-- Icon button -->
<button mat-icon-button>
  <mat-icon svgIcon="android"></mat-icon>
</button>

<!-- You can also combine an icon and text together -->
<button mat-button>
  <mat-icon svgIcon="code-tags"></mat-icon>
  <span>View source</span>
</button>
```

#### CSS adjustments for @angular/material

> Note: As of 9 Jan 2020, you no longer have to specify the manual CSS adjustments shown below.

Also, they say to add this to your global CSS file `styles.css` to solve some alignment issues with @angular/material

```css
button.mat-menu-item {
  line-height: 24px !important;
}

a.mat-menu-item > mat-icon {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.mat-icon svg {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
}
```

#### ❓ Still having errors

As a clue, if you are still having an error at runtime because the application is not able to fetch the `mdi.svg` file although it is present in the `dist/assets` folder when using `ng build` it probably means that something is blocking/intercepting the HTTP request.

**angular-in-memory-api**

For example, when using `angular-in-memory-api` you need you to set property `passThruUnknownUrl: true` when importing `HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule` (see [releated issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11307)) as this allows the URL to the icon-set to pass without interception.

**Server-Side-Rendering**

For SSR you might have to specify the full URL when registering the icon set (see [related issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9728#issuecomment-368848411)) in order to `mdi.svg` file to be fetched correctly.

#### Official @mdi documentation

You can refer to @mdi official [documentation](https://dev.materialdesignicons.com/getting-started/angular#angular-material) if there is anything.

Comment: mmm I tried it but I cann't see the icons, I have anything in assets directory(mdi.svg neither), What can I do? How can I get the file to put in assets?

Comment: did you add `node_modules/@mdi/angular-material/mdi.svg` to the list of `assets` in the `angular.json` file?

Comment: Ups, I forgot to modify the file. Now it return this error https://imgur.com/a/zKdwDYh 
:$

Comment: I've added some information on how to validate if the `mdi.svg` file is correctly copied to you `assets` folder ... I've been able to make it works once it was present.

Comment: I'm the author of the Angular v2+ Material documentation for the MDI icons and I can confirm that you no longer have to add CSS adjustments for the icons when you're using them in a menu: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mdi-icons-menu-so

Comment: I followed your steps and showing the icons correctly ... but this error showing at console
`ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: 'true'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook?`
any idea how to fix it?